# Node/Express Cannot GET /api/auth/login

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am trying to create a login page also same error for register. when I route its shows **[image: Cannot GET /api/auth/login]**,**[*Cannot GET /api/auth/register*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH2S6.png)]*.I have checked all the possible question answers. I'm having trouble with my server routes. is there any problem with my routes? or problem with code the in browser window.

index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const helmet = require("helmet");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const userRoute = require("./routes/users");
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");
const postRoute = require("./routes/posts");

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.MONGO_URL,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
  },
  () => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
  }
);

//middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));

app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("/api/users", userRoute);
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute);

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("Backend server is running!");
});
```

my auth.js where login and register exist.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    //generate new password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    //create new user
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });

    //save user and respond
    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});

//LOGIN
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    !user && res.status(404).json("user not found");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
    !validPassword && res.status(400).json("wrong password")

    res.status(200).json(user)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I only see the `register` route, there is no `login` route. You need to add one.

Comment: basically, i upload the login path , now I upload both login and register can you please check it again

Answer (score 1):

The router for login is using `POST` Method, and if you directly type the URL to the browser, you are sending the `GET` request to the server, you probably need to download a [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) so you can send a `Post` request with body.

Answer (score 0):

You directly send get requests from the browser, you can use [curl](https://curl.se/) or [postman](https://www.postman.com/).

In addition to the @honghai answer, you can't send the response like this:

```
!user && res.status(404).json("user not found");
```

You need to make these changes.

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    // make sure user is not empty {} or [];
    if (!user) res.status(404).json("user not found");

    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)
     // make sure password is not empty {} or [];
    if(!validPassword) res.status(400).json("wrong password");

    res.status(200).json(user)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err)
  }
});
```

Note: you can use [thunderclient](https://www.thunderclient.io/), a lighy weight library to test APIs, I recommend using it.